# mailTo in asp.net MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mailto

how can I use mailto in asp.net MVC 2.0 Website.

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu"><b>Simple MailTo</b></a>
```

I must get email from Model. I need something like this:

```
Html.MailTo(Model.item.email)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the actual question? does that not work?

Comment: I need something like this, Html.MailTo(Model.item.email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="mailto:<%=Model.item.email%>"><b>Simple MailTo</b></a>
```

Comment: ok, how to add atachment with mailto tag ? can you please help